# Compilation extension in SQLAlchemy: functions used in indexes

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I want to make a case-insensitive unique constraint in SQLAlchemy, which would work with both Postgres and SQLite.

In Postgres it is achieved:

- SQL: `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX my_index ON my_table (lower(my_field));`
- SQLAlchemy: `Index('my_index', func.lower(my_field), unique=True)`

In SQLite it is achieved using:

- SQL: `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX my_index ON my_table (my_field COLLATE NOCASE);`
- SQLAlchemy: `Index('my_index', collate(my_field, 'nocase'), unique=True)`

So I'm trying to subclass the `FunctionElement` in order to create my own function-like construct, which would compile either to `my_field COLLATE NOCASE` or `lower(my_field)` depending on DBMS.  I tried to follow [the guide to compilation extension](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/compiler.html), but I'm getting an error (see traceback below), which I can follow through SQLAlchemy source code, but which I cannot understand. I tried subclassing other things, such as `ColumnElement`, `ColumnClause`, `ClauseElement`, but I'm getting similar errors.

Here is the code that reproduces the error. I used version 0.8.2 of SQLAlchemy.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, String, Integer
from sqlalchemy.types import TypeDecorator, VARCHAR
from sqlalchemy import func, Index, collate
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import (
    # Not sure which one to subclass
    FunctionElement, ColumnElement, ColumnClause, ClauseElement
)


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
Base = declarative_base()


class CaseInsensitive(FunctionElement):
    name = 'CaseInsensitive'
    type = VARCHAR()


@compiles(CaseInsensitive, 'sqlite')
def case_insensitive_sqlite(element, compiler, **kw):
    arg1, = list(element.clauses)
    return collate(compiler.process(arg1), 'nocase')


@compiles(CaseInsensitive, 'postgresql')
def case_insensitive_postgresql(element, compiler, **kw):
    arg1, = list(element.clauses)
    return func.lower(compiler.process(arg1))


class MyTable(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'my_table'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    my_field = Column(String)

    __table_args__ = (
        Index('idx', CaseInsensitive(my_field), unique=True),
    )
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmp.py", line 33, in <module>
    class MyTable(Base):
  File "/Users/vladimir/git/wb/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/api.py", line 50, in __init__
    _as_declarative(cls, classname, cls.__dict__)
  File "/Users/vladimir/git/wb/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/base.py", line 222, in _as_declarative
    **table_kw)
  File "/Users/vladimir/git/wb/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/schema.py", line 332, in __new__
    table._init(name, metadata, *args, **kw)
  File "/Users/vladimir/git/wb/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/schema.py", line 400, in _init
    self._init_items(*args)
  File "/Users/vladimir/git/wb/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/schema.py", line 65, in _init_items
    item._set_parent_with_dispatch(self)
  File "/Users/vladimir/git/wb/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/events.py", line 236, in _set_parent_with_dispatch
    self._set_parent(parent)
  File "/Users/vladimir/git/wb/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/schema.py", line 2421, in _set_parent
    ColumnCollectionMixin._set_parent(self, table)
  File "/Users/vladimir/git/wb/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/schema.py", line 2035, in _set_parent
    self.columns.add(col)
  File "/Users/vladimir/git/wb/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/expression.py", line 2477, in add
    self[column.key] = column
  File "/Users/vladimir/git/wb/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/expression.py", line 2296, in __getattr__
    key)
AttributeError: Neither 'CaseInsensitive' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'key'
```

Comment: While this does not concern the question, directly, I had not seen the "table args" construct before. For the assistance of others, if you are wondering about ["__table args__"](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/extensions/declarative.html#declarative-table-args), click on this link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the @compiles method has to return a string.  Also, there's some glitch in how Index is traversing the functionelement here so we need one little workaround:

```
class CaseInsensitive(FunctionElement):
    __visit_name__ = 'notacolumn'
    name = 'CaseInsensitive'
    type = VARCHAR()


@compiles(CaseInsensitive, 'sqlite')
def case_insensitive_sqlite(element, compiler, **kw):
    arg1, = list(element.clauses)
    return compiler.process(collate(arg1, 'nocase'), **kw)


@compiles(CaseInsensitive, 'postgresql')
def case_insensitive_postgresql(element, compiler, **kw):
    arg1, = list(element.clauses)
    return compiler.process(func.lower(arg1), **kw)
```

Comment: I am using this and it works great on its own, but alembic is now getting confused and cannot seem to create an upgrade script for the creation of an index. Alembic gives a migration line such as: "op.create_index('idxUsername', 'users', ['CaseInsensitive'], unique=True)". When I then run "alembic upgrade head", I get an error trace which ends with: "sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) column "CaseInsensitive" does not exist
 'CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "idxUsername" ON users ("CaseInsensitive")' {}". I am not sure how to fine tune the migration script.