# case-sensitive flask model name

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, case-sensitive

I define my models with SQLAlchemy like for instance:

```
class QueryTable(db.Model):
    __searchable__ = ['name']

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), index = True, unique = True)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

    meta = dict()# columnname, type like id: int, name: varchar

    def __repr__(self): #pragma: no cover
        return '<Table %r>' % (self.name)
```

the problem here is, that this allows QueryTables with name table1 and TABLE1 which should be the same in database.

Isn't there a flag in db.Column to do that? I could not found such thing in the documentation.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: See [Compilation extension in SQLAlchemy: functions used in indexes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22154917) for an approach that works in two different databases.

Comment: think I found the problem, was like you said a problem with sqlite, now with mysql it's gone